# How to catch "showLayer" event on the View object

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I need to do some `Actions` on the glisten View based on showing/hiding charm Layer.

The overlay `Layer` is not add in `LayerFactory`. It is just shown by `Layer.show()`

I've found `setOnShowing(...)`, `setOnShown(...)`, `setOnHiding(...)`,`setOnHide(...)`methods on `View` but this `Events` are not fired by overlay with Layer.

Is there some event on `View` which can indicate this `Action`?

Comment: `Layer` controls have those showing/hiding methods too, see [javadoc](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/Layer.html#onShowingProperty).

Comment: I've thought it differently. Is there some simple way to get a notification in the **View** object, that the **View** is overlay with a **Layer** ?

Comment: As long as the layer is showing, it will be over the view. Can't you add a listener to the showing property of the Layer, and verify which View is display at that moment?

Comment: Yes, I can. I've thought that there was some solution without using Layer. But your proposal solves my issue as well. Thanks